# How to solve unitary work problem by Set theory?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

How to solve by set theory - if $A,B$ and $C$ can complete a work individually in $4, 5$ and $6$ days, how many days they will take together to finish the work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "solve by set theory?" This seems  like a typical precalculus problem.

Comment: @manthanomen please edit the tags if you know a good tag

Comment: @user1 I'm hesitant to edit the tag to algebra-precalculus since the question specifically asks for a solution using set theory. I'm just curious about what this could possibly mean

Comment: @Syamal Sengupta what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ completes $1/4$ of work a day
 $B$ completes $1/5$ of work a day
 $C$ completes $1/6$ of work a day
$x$ = the number of days (they will take together to finish the work)

---

$$(1/4) x + (1/5) x+ (1/6) x = 1$$ 
$$x=?$$

Comment: Thanks all of you.  I actually wanted to know what kinds of problems in mathematics could not be solved before Cantor invented Set theory. Apparently problems related to cardinal nos (how many) and ordinal nos (what nth) can be solved by set theory. Wherever I see any set theory problems it is only like x no of boys know maths and physics, y no of boys maths and chemistry etc.etc. that is why I put up a different type of questions where the answer would be in cardinal number. Probably this kind of problem is not ideal for set theory but can I somehow translate it into set theory format?

Comment: hmmmmmmmm, i dont think so